# Concurrency transitions in D3 (circle following filling path)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create simple animated gauge charts, with red points on the end of each circle. Whole example is in here https://jsfiddle.net/yhLch8fc/3/ (please do not solve text position, it's not a problem). I tried to search on stack overflow, but tutorials like [Change starting point of alongPath animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743788/change-starting-point-of-alongpath-animation) are not helping me, because my path is translated by X,Y and rotated. I thing the key part of code is:

```
circle.transition().duration(_duration)
    .attrTween('cx', arcCircleX(_myPath.node()))
    .attrTween('cy', arcCircleY(_myPath.node()));
```

you can easy switch to similar version (code from stack overflow above):

```
circle.transition().duration(_duration)
    .attrTween('transformation', circleTween(_myPath.node()));
```

I don't know why, but it seems the red circle goes to the left side. Maybe it's because the original path is translated and rotated.

(The original version was, when I try to follow filling path, but it does not work either.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rotating the hover `path`, rotate the `g` element that contains both the `path` and the `circle`:

```
enter.append("g").attr("class", "hover")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + _width / 2 + "," + _width / 2 + "), rotate(-90)");
```

Then:

```
circle.transition().duration(_duration)
   .attrTween('transform', circleTween(_myPath.node()));
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vw6PeRnbkn1speXZOvYR?p=preview).  Is that what you were after?

Comment: Hi @Mark, thats cool it almost does what I want, but.. a) do you know why it returns back? b) its not yet concurrency, the red circle needs to follow  the orange line, c) the red circle follows the black line in weird way it looks like it is "arround" :(

Comment: I get it! http://plnkr.co/edit/ttbCRvoP3amSG28n0P07?p=preview but, i was no able to force red circle to stay in center of the path... even if the path is 1px width...